# How to extend Primefaces' DataExporter

Tags: primefaces, primefaces-dataexporter

I am fairly new to PrimeFaces (using 5.1) and am trying to extend DataExporter in order to to use the preProcessor and postProcessor attributes when `type="csv"`. How do I get Primefaces to use the extended class? I thought maybe I could use component-type and component-class in faces-config.xml, but that doesn't work. Does anyone have suggestions on an approach I might take? It seems strange that Primefaces provides preProcessor/postProcessor functionality for xls and pdf but not for csv and xml.